# How to configure a separate folder for CGI scripts with Cheyenne?

Tags: webserver, rebol, cheyenne

I have a web application contained in the following structure:

```
/app-root
+-- /html      ; root files
    /cgi-bin   ; cgi scripts
    /app       ; application files
    /cheyenne  ; Cheyenne binary and config
```

My initial config is:

```
default [
    root-dir %../html
]
```

How do I configure Cheyenne so that when I go to `http://site/cgi-bin/foo.cgi` it will look for foo in `app-root/cgi-bin` and not `app-root/html/cgi-bin`?